# what am i doing wrong?reverse string c++

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, reverse, c-strings

so I want to do the simplest thing in c++ , reverse a string (store the new string) and than print it

my code is :

```
char a[size] , reverse[size];
strcpy(a,"dlow olleh " );
for (int i = 0 ;  i <= strlen(a); i++) {
   reverse[i]= a[strlen(a)-i];
}
cout << reverse ;
```

I must note that when 
 cout << reverse[i] ; 
is inside the for loop every thing wotks fine , but when I wwant to print it as a string it just don't , I cant under stand what ive missed
 cout << reverse[i] ;

Comment: You probably forgot the null-terminator in `reverse`

Comment: im new to c++ , and programing in general  , would you mind to elaborate?

Comment: C-style "strings" (`char` arrays) have a null-terminator `\0` that indicates where the string ends. On second thought your reversing code puts that null-terminator at the first character of `reverse`, so when you try to print it it immediately gets to "the end"

Comment: holysheep you are a genius

Comment: @YarinShani Note that `std::strlen()` is a function that searches from a `char*` start until it finds a `\0'` - every time it's called. That's a lot of calls in your example. Suggestion: Call it once before the loop and store the result and use that in the loop.

Comment: note:Swapping one end of an array to the other is a bad idea. After gone half way, you start swapping back.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first you copy when reversing the string is in fact the null terminator so when you are printing it to console it will not show up since the null terminator is the first in the array so you want to do this instead

```
int size = 12;
char a[12], reverse[12];
strcpy(a, "dlow olleh ");
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++) {
    reverse[i] = a[strlen(a) - (i+1)];
}
reverse[strlen(a)] = '\0';
cout << reverse;
```

Comment: yup totally right i edited the code as u suggested @DavidSchwartz

Answer (score 6):

> what am i doing wrong?

You are using arrays of `char` and functions of the C Standard Library to manipulate strings in C++.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string foo{ "Hello, World!" };
    std::string bar{ foo };
    std::reverse(bar.begin(), bar.end());
    std::cout << '\"' << foo << "\" ==> \"" << bar << "\"\n";
}
```

If – for some reason beyond my comprehension – you *have to* do it by foot, do it in an idiomatic way and provide an interface that takes a pair of iterators:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

void str_reverse(char *begin, char *end)
{
    while (begin < end)
        std::swap(*begin++, *--end);
}

// ...

#include <cstring>
// ...
char foo[]{ "Hello, World!" };
str_reverse(foo, foo + std::strlen(foo));
```

If you can't use `<algorithm>` for whatever reason implement your own `swap()`:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void swap(T &a, T &b)
{
    T tmp{ a };
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Even simpler: `std::string bar{ foo.rbegin(), foo.rend() };`.

Comment: @J. Doe  "You are using arrays of char and functions of the C" This is not wrong. He is learning how to deal with character arrays containing strings. It is an important part of the language that everybody shall know.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow *It is an important part of the language* – I wholeheartedly disagree. The only time that is important to know is when you have to interface with some C-style library. But there is almost never a good reason to use C-style string functions in C++.

Answer (score 5):

In this loop

```
for (int i = 0 ;  i <= strlen(a); i++){
       reverse[i]= a[strlen(a)-i];
```

you are accessing characters beyond the actual characters of the strings.

For example when `i` is equal to 0 you are coping the terminating zero character from the string `a` into the first position of the string `reverse`.

```
reverse[0]= a[strlen(a)-0];
```

the code can be written simpler without for example reduntant calls of the function `strlen`.

```
char a[size], reverse[size];
strcpy( a, "dlrow olleh" );

size_t i = 0;
for ( size_t n = strlen( a ); i < n; i++ ) 
{
    reverse[i] = a[n - i - 1];
}
reverse[i] = '\0';

std::cout << reverse << '\n';
```

Pay attention to that there is the standard algorithm `std::reverse_copy` that does the same task.

Below there is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    const size_t SIZE = 20;
    char a[SIZE], reverse[SIZE];

    std::strcpy( a, "dlrow olleh" );    

    std::cout << a <<'\n';

    auto it = std::reverse_copy( a, a + strlen( a ), reverse );
    *it = '\0';

    std::cout << reverse <<'\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
dlrow olleh
hello world
```

Comment: consider using `strcpy_s` instead of `strcpy`

Comment: `strcpy_s` is only marginally better than `strcpy`. All it does is forces a handler to be called (which typically aborts the program) if you go out of bounds, but you A) have to tell it what the bounds are and be right and B) probably still have a program that crashes. While it's better to fail well, you don't really want to fail at all. Use a `std::string`.